# Form Validation in JavaScript (without using jquery)

Tags: javascript

I have this assignment in my class where we are to make a simple form with three required fields (out of five).  I am having problems with getting my code to work.
This is via my professor...with what he wants
{
On submitting the form, the browser should check that :
Values for the required fields have been entered
Use regular expressions to check that the form of the entered input is proper for the email, telephone, and website fields. The forms to check for are:
Email: [alphanumeric string including . and _ ]@ [alphanumeric string including . and _ ]. [alpha string]
Telephone: Either (ddd)ddd-dddd or ddd-ddd-dddd etc
Website: www.[alphanumeric string including . _ -].[com or net etc]
If any error is found, the form should not be submitted and appropriate error messages should be generated.
}

All validation must be "client side" i.e. on the browser using Javascript (not on any server and no Jquery or any programming other than Javascript and the required HTML). Use of any authoring tools is strictly and expressly forbidden.

This what I have now.  Please help.  Below is the code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 <script language = "JavaScript">
<!--
function validateForm(){
//This is to check that required fields are filled
    var x = document.contact.Name.value;
    var y = document.contact.Email.value;
    var z = document.contact.Website.value;
    var p = document.contact.Phone.value;

    if(x==null || x ==""){
        alert('Name must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    if (y ==null || y == ""){
        alert('Email must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    if (z == null || z == ""){
        alert('Website must be filled out');
        return false;
    }


    if(!isEmail()){
        alert('This is not a correct Email format');
    }
    if (!isTelephone()){
        var errorText = document.createTextNode(
            "This is not a correct Phone number format");
    }
    if(!isWeb()){
        errorText = document.createTextNode(
            "This is not the correct Website format");
    }


}

function isTelephone(){
    //This checks that the phone number is in the required format
    return document.contact.Phone.value.match(
        /^\(\d\d\d-d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d$/);
    }
function isEmail(){
    //This is for checking email format
    return document.contact.Email.value.match(
        /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/);
    }

function isWeb(){
    return document.contact.Website.value.match(
        /^([wW]{3}\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{3,}\[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a‌​-zA-Z]{2,})?$/);
    }
-->
</script>


<body>
<form name="contact" action="" method="post" onSubmit = "return validateForm();">

Name: <input type="textbox" name="Name" value=""  > <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Company: <input type="textbox" name="Company" value="" > <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Email: <input type="textbox" name="Email" value=""  > <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Telephone: <input type="textbox" name="Telephone" value="" > <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Website: <input type="textbox" name="Website" value="" ><font color = red>*Required </font><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details">


<input type="reset" value="Clear" 
    ONCLICK="
    alert('This will clear the form.');
    Name.value=' '
    Company.value=' '
    Email.value=' '
    Telephone.value=' '
    Website.value=' '"><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function is never called - you call the validation in `onSubmit` but your form buttons are of `type = button` so they never submit the form

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details">`

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- https://jsfiddle.net/vduwxjmv/

This can be done without JavaScript also using `required` attribute at each html control for which value is mandatory. And for clear you can use input type as `reset`.

**HTML:-**

```
<form name="contact" action="" method="post">

Name: <input type="textbox" name="Name" value="" required> <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Company: <input type="textbox" name="Company" value=""> <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Email: <input type="textbox" name="Email" value="" required> <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Telephone: <input type="textbox" name="Telephone" value="" > <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Website: <input type="textbox" name="Website" value="" required><font color = red>*Required </font><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details">


<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

Comment: its browser dependent. some of browsers not supports its complete so js jquery is good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check by using the following JavaScript code

```
var result = $("#form")[0].checkValidity();
```

or you may change input button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details">
```

Comment: By the way `jQuery` is not tagged mate!

Comment: Because the prof says we cannot use jQuery in this assignment.  Therefore I did not tag it.

Comment: you change input button to submit and try <input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details"> or you Document.getElementById("form").checkValidity();

Comment: I made those changes but the alert messages still do not trigger when the required fields are blank

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<form name="contact" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required="required" /> <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Company: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Company" placeholder="Company" /> <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Email: <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="required" /> <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Telephone: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Telephone" placeholder="Telephone"/> <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Website: <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="Website" placeholder="Website" required="required" /><font color = red>*Required </font><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details">
<input type="reset" value="Clear"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

change the type from button to submit.
on giving the type as reset ,it will clear the contents.
on giving required="required", that field will be considered as a mandatory one.

Comment: Where's the JavaScript?

Comment: without the script ,we can implemented the validation by use of required attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script language = "JavaScript">

function validateForm(thisVar){ alert('method Called From: ');alert(thisVar.value);alert(thisVar.name);
//This is to check that required fields are filled
    var x = document.contact.Name.value;
    var y = document.contact.Email.value;
    var z = document.contact.Website.value;
    var p = document.contact.Phone.value;

    if(x==null || x ==""){
        alert('Name must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    if (y ==null || y == ""){
        alert('Email must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    if (z == null || z == ""){
        alert('Website must be filled out');
        return false;
    }


    if(!isEmail()){
        alert('This is not a correct Email format');
    }
    if (!isTelephone()){
        var errorText = document.createTextNode(
            "This is not a correct Phone number format");
    }
    if(!isWeb()){
        errorText = document.createTextNode(
            "This is not the correct Website format");
    }


}

function isTelephone(){
    //This checks that the phone number is in the required format
    return document.contact.Phone.value.match(
        /^\(\d\d\d-d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d$/);
    }
function isEmail(){
    //This is for checking email format
    return document.contact.Email.value.match(
        /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/);
    }

function isWeb(){
    return document.contact.Website.value.match(
        /^([wW]{3}\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{3,}\[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a‌​-zA-Z]{2,})?$/);
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="contactForm" action="" method="post" onSubmit = "return validateForm(this);">

Name: <input type="textbox" name="Name" value=""  > <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Company: <input type="textbox" name="Company" value="" > <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Email: <input type="textbox" name="Email" value=""  > <font color = red>*Required </font><br>
Telephone: <input type="textbox" name="Telephone" value="" > <font color = red>Optional </font><br>
Website: <input type="textbox" name="Website" value="" ><font color = red>*Required </font><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details" onclick="validateForm(this);">


<input type="reset" value="Clear" 
    ONCLICK="
    alert('This will clear the form.');
    Name.value=' '
    Company.value=' '
    Email.value=' '
    Telephone.value=' '
    Website.value=' '"><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can validate it by two ways ---

1. use Submit type button
2. call validationForm on button click

Like --

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Contact Details">
```

or

```
<input type="button" onclick="return validationForm();" value="Submit Contact Details">
```

you can check method call from to times 1st from onclick 2nd from onsubmit
Dont forget to appreciate (vote up).

Comment: use it after removing Html Comment from you Js method

Comment: The alerts still won't trigger

Comment: you putted your js function between html comment like <!--   -->.Remove its first.

Comment: @Zirgri2612 I'm having problems with the function calls

Comment: your function is not present in html page (because of html comment )

Comment: You haven't see the alder in live code snippet after run